# MYSQL/PHP BATCH UPDATE

Tags: mysql, batch-file, updates

I want to create a batch delete and/or update screen for records similar to how the iphone lets you batch delete text messages  In other words when you click edit, it shows a checkbox next to all the records and you can then click a button that deletes them or changes a value.

I have discovered following syntax to insert a bunch of rows:

```
insert into tbl (...) values (...) (...) (...) ...
```

There also seems to be a way to batch delete using:

```
delete from tbl where id IN (1,2,3)
```

Is there a way to do a batch update?

I think I could then just collect an array of the id numbers for the records and run either a delete or update query depending on what button is pushed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WHERE` condition same like you did for `DELETE` query like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col1='...', col2='...' WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

[See this *SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00b24/1)

Comment: Thanks!  First time I have seen sqlfiddle.